# How to send notification using parse for particular group members in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have create an account in parse.com. I am using this single account for my three project.

I need to send notifications. Each application having different app name and package name.

my contents are in parse:

## project 1

- app name : App1
- package name : com.example.app1
- channels : science , maths, physics.

## project 2

- app name : App2
- package name : com.example.app2
- channels : economics , chemistry.

## project 3

- app name : App3
- package name : com.example.app3
- channels : engilsh, physics.

Here there are some channels are common this account. So the notification will send two projects at a time. Now i need to send notification for particular project with particular channel.

For example Now i need to send notification for physics in App1. How can i segregate that one.

**My questions are:**

1. Is it possible to do? If yes means how?
2. If it is not possible means whats is another way?
3. May i create an separate account for each application? Is it correct way?

Any body can tell me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer to SENDING PUSHES TO CHANNELS https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use same Parse Account for multiple apps and send push directed for some specific app.
In parse installation table there is an attribute (column ) appIdentifier which stores package name of app.
So you can write query like this:

```js
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo('appIdentifies', "App Package name")
query.equalTo('channels', 'your channel');
Parse.Push.send({
  where: query, // Set our Installation query
  data: {
    alert: "Willie Hayes injured by own pop fly."
  }
}, {
  success: function() {
    // Push was successful
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Handle error
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try This.

```
ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("appIdentifier", "com.example.app1");
query.whereEqualTo("channels", "physics"); 
push.setQuery(query);
push.setMessage("Hello");
push.sendInBackground();
```